# Construct Pandas DataFrame whose (i,j)th entry is the probability that a person aged i+100 will still be alive after j years

Tags: python, pandas

The following function takes the probability of a person aged 100+i dying in the next year (conditional on them being alive at the start of the year) and returns the probability that they will be alive after j years (for 0 < j < 21):

```
import pandas as pd


def prob_in_force():

    # i-th entry of qx_curve gives the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will die in the next year
    # (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    qx_curve = pd.Series([0.378702, 0.402588, 0.42709, 0.452127, 0.477608, 0.503432, 0.529493, 0.555674, 0.581857,
                          0.607918, 0.633731, 0.659171, 0.684114, 0.708442, 0.732042, 0.754809, 0.776648, 0.797477,
                          0.817225, 1], index=range(101, 121))

    # i-th entry of px_curve gives the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will NOT die in the next year
    # (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    px_curve = (1 - qx_curve).to_list()

    # Construct a DataFrame whose (i, j)th entry is the probability that a life aged i+j+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will NOT
    # die in the next year (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    df_px_arr = pd.DataFrame([px_curve[i:] + [0] * i for i in range(1, 21)], index=[x for x in range(101, 121)])

    # Calculate the cumulative product of the px values in each row of the DataFrame constructed above. The (i, j)th
    # entry of this DataFrame is the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will still be alive after j
    # years
    return df_px_arr.cumprod(axis=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(prob_in_force())
```

In practice, the qx curve is read from a csv file, so the instantiation of this variable can be ignored for the purpose of improving this code. The line that I suspect leaves most room for improvement is

```
df_px_arr = pd.DataFrame([px_curve[i:] + [0] * i for i in range(1, 21)], index=[x for x in range(101, 121)])
```

I suspect that both the speed and readability of this line leave room for improvement.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: In your current formulation the first value of `qx_curve` is always ignored. Are you sure that this is what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in the comments, I don't trust that it's correct for you to skip the first element of your input; but for now I'll assume that this is intentional.

You don't need Pandas for any of this, and cutting straight to Numpy is possible (though you'll later see that this isn't always beneficial). The input and output can be trivially converted from and to Pandas if needed.

You're correct in thinking that there are speed concerns in this code. List comprehensions are often the death of performance in Pandas/Numpy. A fully-vectorised version is possible. The strided version I've demonstrated takes some spooky shortcuts in constructing a triangularised two-dimensional matrix with low overhead.

Numerically what I show here is equivalent, verified with regression tests and inspection. Functionally, it doesn't produce a dataframe. About the only thing you were using in Pandas that would be worth reintroducing after the fact is an age index, though you haven't shown any information on its use.

Of course, as with anything performance: measuring the results is critical, and - very interestingly - Numpy's `cumprod` implementation, whereas it has very low startup cost, scales poorly at O(n^2) whereas the original method and @tdy's method scale linearly. If you have fewer than ~1000 elements, one of the Numpy methods is best; otherwise, use one of the Pandas methods.

### Suggested

```
from timeit import timeit

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import default_rng


def prob_in_force_old(qx_curve: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # i-th entry of px_curve gives the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will NOT die in the next year
    # (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    px_curve = (1 - qx_curve).to_list()

    # Construct a DataFrame whose (i, j)th entry is the probability that a life aged i+j+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will NOT
    # die in the next year (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    df_px_arr = pd.DataFrame([px_curve[i:] + [0] * i for i in range(1, 21)], index=[x for x in range(101, 121)])

    # Calculate the cumulative product of the px values in each row of the DataFrame constructed above. The (i, j)th
    # entry of this DataFrame is the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will still be alive after j
    # years
    return df_px_arr.cumprod(axis=1)


def prob_in_force_rowwise(qx_curve: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = len(qx_curve)
    prod = np.zeros((n, n), dtype=qx_curve.dtype)

    px_curve: np.ndarray = 1 - qx_curve[1:]

    for y in range(0, n-1):
        px_curve[y:].cumprod(out=prod[y, :n-y-1])
    return prod


def prob_in_force_strided(qx_curve: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    n = len(qx_curve)

    # Tricky: make an array of double the width, so that when we broadcast-triangularise,
    # the lower right fills with zeros.
    px_curve = np.zeros(2*n, dtype=qx_curve.dtype)
    px_curve[:n-1] = 1 - qx_curve[1:]

    # Broadcast-triangularise. This is an efficient view construction that
    # should not take up any additional memory.
    broadcasted = np.broadcast_to(px_curve, (n, 2*n))
    bytes = broadcasted.dtype.itemsize
    slid = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(px_curve, shape=(n, n), strides=(bytes, bytes))

    return slid.cumprod(axis=1)


def prob_in_force_tdy(qx_curve):
    return pd.DataFrame({
        i - 1: qx_curve.rsub(1).shift(-i, fill_value=0)
        for i in range(1, 21)
    }).cumprod(axis=1)


def test_regression() -> None:
    def isclose(a, b):
        assert np.allclose(a, b, rtol=0, atol=1e-9)

    # i-th entry of qx_curve gives the probability that a life aged i+100 (for 1 < i < 21) will die in the next year
    # (conditional on being alive at the start of the year)
    as_array = np.array((0.378702, 0.402588, 0.42709, 0.452127, 0.477608, 0.503432, 0.529493, 0.555674, 0.581857,
                         0.607918, 0.633731, 0.659171, 0.684114, 0.708442, 0.732042, 0.754809, 0.776648, 0.797477,
                         0.817225, 1))
    as_series = pd.Series(as_array)

    for method in (prob_in_force_old, prob_in_force_strided, prob_in_force_rowwise, prob_in_force_tdy):
        qx_curve = (
            as_array if method in (prob_in_force_strided, prob_in_force_rowwise) else as_series
        )
        result = method(qx_curve)
        if isinstance(result, pd.DataFrame):
            result = result.values
        assert result.shape == (20, 20)
        isclose(0, result.min())
        isclose(0.597412, result.max())
        isclose(0.02894936687892334, result.mean())
        isclose(11.579746751569337, result.sum())


def test_performance() -> None:
    times = []
    rand = default_rng(seed=0)

    n_values = np.round(10**np.linspace(0.5, 5, 50))

    methods = {
        prob_in_force_old, prob_in_force_strided, prob_in_force_rowwise, prob_in_force_tdy,
    }

    for n in n_values:
        n = int(n)

        times.append(('ideal_n',  n, (n/1000) * 5e-3))
        if 1e2 <= n <= 1e4:
            times.append(('ideal_n2', n, (n/1000)**2 * 5e-3))

        as_array = rand.random(n)
        as_series = pd.Series(as_array)

        slow = set()
        for method in methods:
            qx_curve = (
                as_array if method in (prob_in_force_strided, prob_in_force_rowwise)
                else as_series
            )
            def run():
                method(qx_curve)
            t = timeit(run, number=1)
            times.append((method.__name__, n, t))
            if t > 0.2:
                slow.add(method)
        methods -= slow

    df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=('method', 'n', 't'))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    sns.lineplot(data=df, x='n', y='t', hue='method', ax=ax)
    ax.set(xscale='log', yscale='log')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_regression()
    test_performance()
```

[image: Time complexity]

Answer (score 4):

1. Pandas has some built-in methods that are relevant here:

   - [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html): Instead of converting to a list and doing `px_curve[i:] + [0] * i`, we can keep it as a Series and do `px_curve.shift(-i, fill_value=0)`.
   - [`Series.rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html): `1 - qx_curve` is equivalent to `qx_curve.rsub(1)`. In most cases, I would still use the former as it's more readable, but the latter is useful when chaining methods.
2. The column labels are off by 1. Currently they're labeled `[0, 1, …, 19]` but should actually be `[1, 2, …, 20]` to match `range(1, 21)`.
3. `index = list(range(...))` is faster and more idiomatic than `index = [x for x in range(...)]`. However, this step of rebuilding the `index` is unnecessary if we use [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html).

---

#### Suggested

Build the matrix using a dict comprehension of [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
def prob_in_force():
    # qx_curve = ...

    px_curve = 1 - qx_curve
    df = pd.DataFrame({i: px_curve.shift(-i, fill_value=0) for i in range(1, 21)})
    return df.cumprod(axis=1)
```

```
>>> prob_in_force()
            1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12            13            14            15            16            17            18   19   20
101  0.597412  0.342263  0.187517  0.097957  0.048642  0.022887  0.010169  0.004252  0.001667  0.000611  0.000208  0.000066  1.916801e-05  5.136222e-06  1.259355e-06  2.812796e-07  5.696558e-08  1.041188e-08  0.0  0.0
102  0.572910  0.313882  0.163969  0.081422  0.038310  0.017022  0.007118  0.002791  0.001022  0.000348  0.000110  0.000032  8.597454e-06  2.108018e-06  4.708301e-07  9.535393e-08  1.742831e-08  0.000000e+00  0.0  0.0
103  0.547873  0.286204  0.142120  0.066868  0.029711  0.012424  0.004871  0.001784  0.000608  0.000192  0.000056  0.000015  3.679493e-06  8.218221e-07  1.664379e-07  3.042068e-08  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0  0.0
...
118  0.182775  0.000000  0.000000       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
119  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
120  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

#### One-liner

Just for demonstration (not recommended), we can technically reduce it to a one-liner by chaining [`Series.rsub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) and [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
def prob_in_force():
    # qx_curve = ...

    return pd.DataFrame({i: qx_curve.rsub(1).shift(-i, fill_value=0) for i in range(1, 21)}).cumprod(axis=1)
```